# How to import number from scene 1 to scene 2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I import number from another scene? For example:

> scene1 script

```
if(...) {
   a = 1;
} else {
   a = 0;
}
```

How to import `a` to the next scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do this is by making the scene load async, and passing the value through code to the object that's supposed to receive it in the next scene:

```
var valueToPass = 2;
var asyncOp = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("otherScene");
asyncOp.OnCompleted += () => 
{
    // this code runs once the second scene is loaded
    FindObjectOfType<SomeOtherObject>().PropertyToFill = valueToPass;
}
```

I wrote the code off the top of my head,  it probably won't compile (didn't have Unity on hand to test it) but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a as a static variable. it will keep the value.

`public static int a;`

Comment: Bad idea, that static value will stick around for some time and become a possible source of bugs.

Comment: Values can be passed to another scene in various ways. most common of them are:

* PlayerPrefs
* Static variables

Comment: Indeed, but statics have caused me quite a few headaches before.